# Why is it raining only over generated bodies of water?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

[On Minecraft I notice that it rains only over water (links to YouTube video showing the issue better)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kifz8BSZgbc&feature=youtu.be):

[image]

I haven't played Minecraft for a while: is this a recent change that I missed?
I first noticed this on a server so I tried single-player, but however the issue persists.

I've tracked it down to *generated* bodies of water (e.g, not water that the player has put down or any part of the world that is modified where water flows), that is:

- Rivers;
- Streams;
- Lakes;
- Sea

If I dig a large hole and fill it with water from a nearby natural water source (where the rain is falling), rain will not fall over the body of water I created.

Thinking that this was an issue with the GPU, I upgraded the GPU (small upgrade, but a huge difference and I needed the upgrade anyhow) but the problem persists. I've also tried reinstalling the game (**I have not tried an earlier version (snapshot) of the game however, and I'll do that shortly**) and that didn't work either.

I have this issue in the Savanna and Desert biomes, and I haven't tried another biome type.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It has to do with [biomes](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Biome), and is *not* in any way a bug;

Judging by the acacia trees, you are in a [dry/warm biome](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Biome#Dry.2FWarm_biomes) (either a Savanna or Plateau). In these Biomes it doesn't rain or snow, it only becomes overcast.

But all the naturally generated bodies of water; like [rivers, lakes](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Biome#Medium.2FLush_biomes), and [oceans](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Biome#Neutral_biomes) will rain, because they are separate (and not dry) biomes.

Comment: Interesting. Could be something that needs to be changed (it shouldn't rain in those biomes at all, even over water).

Comment: It is a bit odd to have vast expanses or dry biome(s) broken up by tiny strips where it rains, but it is how minecraft works.

Comment: @cybermonkey It doesn't rain in the dry biomes; only in the rivers/oceans (which are separate biomes from the dry ones).

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. A river through a dry biome might technically be a separate biome (implementation detail), but it's not separate to the player, and it looks *weird*.

Comment: @Blorgbeard: This is no more of a bug than the fact that you can chop out the bottom of a tree and leave the rest hanging in midair.  It's a deliberate simplification of reality.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Plus I hear the sound of rain, even where there isn't any. If that's not a bug then I don't know what is..

Comment: "It's not a bug, it's a feature" - that line only works in the ears of marketing and support, not in the ears of customers. If it looks like a duck...

Comment: @Peter Do you also believe that floating tree parts are a bug? Are floating generated landmasses a bug? A 'bug' implies that the software exhibits an unintended feature. The fact that dry biomes do not show rain but river and ocean features in the biome do show rain over those blocks is intended behaviour, whether or not it's realistic.